# Find number of rows in a column of a particular sheet in macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling to write a function in VBA which takes sheet name and column as parameters and returns last used row number in that column of that sheet.

I used the following code:

```
Worksheet("sheetname").Range("e2").End(xlDown).Row
```

But it returns wrong values... like 104567

Please provide me the code to find row count in a particular column of particular sheet.

Answer (score 6):

The `1` in the code is the column you would like to check. You can change `ActiveSheet` to any other valid worksheet object.

```
lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 1):

An explanation: The number is actually 1,048,576 - the bottom of the worksheet. What it means is that there are no non-empty cells in the column "E:E" below row 2. The solution provided by **braX** is a standard and a very good way of handling this. In case you want to spec the column by name, you can do this:

```
Worksheet("sheetname").Range("e" & Worksheet("sheetname").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```